# In C++ multithreading applications, should I pass lambda or function with parameters?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, lambda

I have just started learning about multithreading in C++...
is there a difference between `t1` and `t2`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

std::mutex mutexCout;

//prints the value of x, and then increments it
//param: int value to display and increment
void foo (int& x)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard_(mutexCout);
    std::cout << "x is " << x << "\n";
    ++x;
}

//testing different ways to call a function with reference
int main() 
{
    int x = 5;
    //is t1 different from t2???
    std::thread t1 ([&] {foo(x)};
    std::thread t2 (foo, std::ref(x));
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard_(mutexCout);
        std::cout << "x is " << x << "\n";
    }

    //added after posting the question
    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This question is propably better asked at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). I would opt for the simpler construct, which is t2. t1 needs a special language feature (lambda), so why use that if there is no obvious benefit.

Comment: @zett42, I would have said that the t1 initializer was the simple one.  (Ignoring the syntax error)  t2 needs a special library feature (`std::ref`), so why use that if there is no obvious benefit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume you fixed it with calls to join.

Using `[&]` capture for lambdas that outlive the current scope or who run in a different thread is generally a bad idea: you should have sufficiently little shared state in both cases that explicitly stating what you are sharing like `[&x]` isn't a serious overhead problem, and will prevent you from accidentally sharing the wrong data in dangerous ways due to seemingly innocuous typos or naming errors.

In general, using raw C++ `std` threading APIs in an application is only useful when the application is small and simple, and the threading limited.  Past that point you'll want thread pools, continuations, signals, etc.  The C++ threading primitives are enough to write those, but they don't provide those.

I have found that when I'm writing my own wrappers, expecting the caller to pass in a nullary callable (or one with only arguments it expects the threading framework to provide) is far more sane than doing what `std` did where you can also pass arguments.  This becomes more viable with the [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) additions to lambda syntax, which permits moving in arguments and calculated binds.

So in "real" code mine would look like:

```
my_future<void> r = some_thread_pool.add_task([&x] {foo(x)});
```

Comment: thank you for the "live" example. I understand that `some_thread_pool` is an instance of class, but what is `my_future` type for?

Comment: @Anton In my case, it is a future that supports continuations like `.then( more code )`, which in turn returns yet another `my_future`.  Basically, `std::future` isn't enough for my needs.  Other people might need futures that are multiple-waitable.  These things may be coming in future iterations of C++, but for now I have to write them myself.

Comment: @Anton, a "future" is an object that is used to pass a result from one thread to another.  I don't know specifically about the C++ standard library, but in many programming languages/libraries, there is something called a "future" or a "promise" into which a producer thread can store a value, and from which a consumer can fetch it.  Usually, there is a method that allows the consumer to wait for the value if the producer hasn't stored it yet.  It's kind of like a 1-deep, blocking queue that can only be used one time.  It may also have a way to pass an exception from one thread to the other.

Comment: Destroying a joinable `std::thread` has well-defined behavior: `terminate()`. It's not a particularly useful behavior, to be sure...

Comment: @t.c was thnking post detatch, my bad

Answer (score 1):

There's little difference between the two in terms of runtime behavior, but I would be very careful with using universal capture by reference and threads. E.g. both pieces of code above are passing an address to the stack in `main` and nothing guarantees that `main` is still executing when the threads do indirect through this address. Hence undefined behavior. With universal capture by reference in lambdas, this is much more likely to happen by accident. Using either value capture or explicit captures is safer.

I'm not sure I agree with the comment above that the lambda is using a more complex language feature. In both cases, something has to package up a structure to contain the argument state to pass across the thread boundary. For this case, since invocation is passing just one pointer to the thread function, it could be done without an intermediate structure. (The lambda version will likely have to use a structure.) However there's still a fair bit of C++ complexity happening in argument forwarding, etc.

If one is really interested in what is going on, it is best to look at the generated assembly from a good compiler, which for a small example like this is pretty doable. (And comparing to the straight pthreads code in old school C might also be instructive.) I don't have time to do this right now but my pretty good guess is the differences are immaterial compared to issues of correctness, portability, and code readability.

I do find lambdas to be a very mixed bag in whether they make code easier or harder to read. If one is simply passing some arguments to a thread function, it seems the lambda will be harder to read as one has to verify nothing fancy is happening inside the curly brackets in the lambda. (And it's C++ so through operator overloads, etc. a thing that just looks like a function call could be quite complex.) If one is putting the entire execution in the lambda and it is small and thus saves having to go look at a separate thread function, then it might make the code easier to read.

Comment: Lambdas don't make code easier or harder to read.  _Programmers_ do that.  Lambdas are just one of the many tools that a programmer can use to achieve either effect.